# Can a nontrivial $\phi \in Gal(\bar K /\bar k )$ preserve all algebraically closed subfields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, fields

The answer is "yes" if $\bar K = \overline{k(x)}$ (in fact, *every* $\phi \in Gal(\overline{k(x)}/\bar k)$ preserves all algebraically closed subfields -- there's only two of them, so it's not that hard!), but I'm not sure about higher transcendence degree. I suspect that for large enough $\bar K$ the answer must be "no", probably already at $\bar K = \overline{k(x,y)}$.

To clarify, as LSpice points out below, there are plenty of automorphisms $\phi \in Gal(\overline{k(x,y)}/\bar k)$ which do *not* preserve all algebraically closed subfields -- e.g. automorphisms swapping $x$ and $y$. So it's certainly not the case that *all* $\phi \in Gal(\bar K / \bar k)$ preserve all algebraically closed subfields. The question is for what $\bar K, \bar k$ there exists *some* such $\phi$ (other than the identity).

For context, we might perturb the question. There are no nontrivial automorphisms of $k(x,y)/k$ preserving all subfields. Any automorphisms of a vector space preserving all subspaces, is multiplication by a scalar.

I'd really like to ask this question for an arbitrary first-order theory, but perhaps I will save that for a future post.

Comment: Isn't there an element $\phi \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k(x, y)}/\overline k)$ that swaps $x$ and $y$, hence doesn't preserve $\overline{k(x)}$?

Comment: Sure, so the $\phi$ I'm asking for can't be that one!

Comment: Oh dear, sorry, I misread "a … $\phi$ … preserves all" as "all … $\phi$ … preserve all"!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question using a little bit of model theory (actually combinatorial geometry). Since the theory of algebraically closed fields is strongly minimal, the algebraic closure induces a pregeometry. More precisely given $\bar k \subseteq \bar K$ there is a pregeometry $G(\bar K/\bar k) = (\bar K, cl_{\bar k})$ associated to it where $cl_{\bar k}(A)$ is the algebraic closure of the field generated by $\bar k$ and $A$. Now your question becomes if there is a nontrivial automorphism of $\bar K/\bar k$ that fixes setwise all closed sets in $G(\bar K/\bar k)$.

Since we are interested only in the closed sets the right object to look at is the *geometry* $\underline G$ associated to the *pregeometry* $G = (A, cl)$. To obtain this we define an equivalence relation on $A$ as $a \sim b$ if $cl(a) = cl(b)$ and look at $(A \setminus cl(\emptyset)) / \sim$. The closure is defined as $cl(B/\sim) = \{a/\sim : a \in cl(B)\}$. Now an automorphism of $G$ induces an automorphism of $\underline G$ and it preserves closed sets of $G$ if and only if the induced automorphism on $\underline G$ is the identity.

To sum up we associate a geometry $\underline G(\bar K/\bar k)$ to the pair $\bar k \subseteq \bar K$. There is a map $\sigma : Aut(\bar K/\bar k) \to Aut(\underline G(\bar K/\bar k))$ and your questions is whether it is injective. This map actually factors through $Aut(\bar K)_{\{\bar k\}}$ - the set of automorphisms of $\bar K$ that fix $\bar k$ *setwise*. So let $\chi : Aut(\bar K)_{\{\bar k\}} \to Aut(\underline G(\bar K/\bar k))$ be the natural map, (i.e. $\chi(g)(cl_{\bar k}(x)) = cl_{\bar k}(gx)$) and $i : Aut(\bar K/\bar k) \to Aut(\bar K)_{\bar k}$ be the inclusion map. Then $\sigma = \chi \circ i$.

The map $\chi$ is studied by Evans and Hrushovski in [The Automorphism Group of the Combinatorial Geometry of an Algebraically Closed Field](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/52.2.209/abstract) (Journal of LMS, Volume 52, 1995) under the assumption that the transcendence degree of $\bar K$ over $\bar k$ is at least $5$. One of their main results is that it is surjective. On page 214 they also remark that if the characteristic of $\bar K$ is nonzero, then the kernel of $\chi$ consists of powers of Frobenius and otherwise it is trivial. This then implies that the kernel of $\sigma$ is trivial. Therefore the answer to your question is negative if the transcendence degree of $\bar K$ over $\bar k$ is at least $5$.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is just what I was looking for. I think I can show it now in transcendence degree 2, I'll post something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an argument that only trivial such automorphisms exist already for $\overline{k(x,y)}/k$ (note that in this post I don't require the automorphism to fix $\bar k$). It may be similar to the argument in the Evans-Hrushovski paper linked to by Levon Haykazyan; I haven't looked closely.

Let $\bar K / k$ have transcendence degree $\geq 2$. Say that $\phi \in Gal(\bar K / k)$ is *infinitesimal* if it preserves all algebraically-closed subfields. Let $G \subset Gal(\bar K / k)$ be the group of infinitesimal automorphisms. Note that $G$ is normal in $Gal(\bar K / k)$.

**Lemma:** If $\phi \in G$, then $\phi$ has no fixed points outside of $\bar k$.

**Proof.** Assume there is $\phi \in G$ with fixed points outside of $\bar k$. Then we can find $s$ a fixed point and $t$ a non-fixed point with $s,t$ algebraically independent. Let $u = \phi(t) - t$. Then

- Because $\phi$ preserves $\overline{k(t)}$, we have $\overline{k(u)} \subseteq \overline{k(t)}$, since $u = \phi(t) - t$;
- Because $\phi$ preserves $\overline{k(s+t)}$ we have $\overline{k(u)} \subseteq \overline{k(s+t)}$, since $u = \phi(t) - t = \phi(s+t) - (s+t)$.

Both these inclusions cannot be equalities, because $t$ and $s+t$ are algebraically indepdent and consqeuently $\overline{k(s+t)} \neq \overline{k(t)}$. But from either inclusion being proper, we conclude that $u \in \bar k$. So $\phi(t) = t + u$ with $u \in \bar k$. Let $1 < d \in \mathbb{N}$ be coprime to the characteristic of $k$. If $t^d$ is not fixed by $\phi$, then the same arguments as before show that $\phi(t^d) = t^d + u'$ with $u' \in \bar k$; if $t^d$ is fixed by $\phi$ then we still have such an equation with $u' = 0$. But we also have $\phi(t^d) = (t+u)^d$, so that $(x+u)^d - x^d - u' = 0$ is a polynomial over $\bar k$ satisfied by $t$. Because $d$ is not 1 or divisible by the characteristic of $k$ and $u \neq 0$, this is not the zero polynomial. So $t \in \bar k$, a contradiction. So there are no fixed points outside of $\bar k$.

**Corollary:** If $\phi \in G$ and $s \in \bar K \setminus \bar k$, then $\phi$ is uniquely determined by the value of $\phi(s)$.

**Proof.** If there is $\psi \in G$ with $\psi(s) = \phi(s)$, then $\psi^{-1}\phi$ fixes $s$ and so must be the identity by the lemma.

**Corollary:** $G$ is the group of Frobenius automorphisms, and in particular the part fixing $\bar k$ is trivial.

**Proof.** It suffices to show this for $\bar K = \overline{k(s,t)}$. For any automorphism $\alpha \in Gal(\overline{k(s)}/k)$, choose a lift $\beta \in Gal(\overline{k(s,t)}/k)$ which fixes $t$. If $\phi \in G$, then $\beta \phi \beta^{-1} \in G$. We have $\beta \phi \beta^{-1}(t) = \phi(t)$; by the corollary, then, $\beta \phi \beta^{-1} = \phi$. So $\phi(s) = \beta \phi \beta^{-1}(s) = \alpha \phi|_{\overline{k(s)}}\alpha^{-1}(s)$. That is, $\phi|_{\overline{k(s)}}$ lies in the center of $Gal(\overline{k(s)}/k)$, which is known to consist only of the Frobenius automorphisms. Since $\phi \in G$ is determined by $\phi|_{\overline{k(s)}}$, it follows that that $\phi$ is also a Frobenius automorphism.

Actually, I'm not sure I can prove that the center of $Gal(\overline{k(s)}/k)$ is just the Frobenius maps. So here's another argument. When we allow $s,t$ to vary, $Gal(\overline{k(s,t)}/k)$ is generated by elements like $\alpha$ above. So we see that $\phi$ in fact commutes with all of $Gal(\overline{k(s,t)}/k)$. This allows us to extend $\phi$ to an automorphism of $\bar K / k$ for any transcendence degree -- we can define it locally, and we get a homomorphism because we only have to check addition and multiplication, which are binary operations, and knowing how $\phi$ works on degree-2 extensions lets us handle this. Then we can pass to a very large $\bar K$ and conclude that because $\phi$ commutes with all automorphisms, it must be definable, i.e. definable by a polynomial. Since $\phi$ is invertible, the polynomial can only have one root, so it must be a Frobenius map.