# Automorphisms that preserve every algebraically closed set

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a theory, and $A$ be an algebraically closed set. Let $L$ be the lattice of algebraically closed subsets of $A$. Can one understand the kernel of the natural map $\chi: Aut(A) \to Aut(L)$? (The *image* of this map is also interesting to study, but it really is the *kernel* I'd like to know about.)

When $T$ is "nice" (maybe some kind of stability condition) and $A$ is "large enough" (maybe some kind of rank condition **EDIT:** as became clear in the discussion in the comments, more than just a size condition is necessary -- some kind of "complexity" or "nondegeneracy" condition on the algebraic closure operation is probably necessary), I would hope that the following are canonically isomorphic:

1. $\ker \chi$;
2. The center $Z(Aut(\overline{\{\emptyset\}}))$ of the automorphism group of the minimal algebraic set;
3. The center $Z(Aut(U))$ of the automorphism group of a monster model;
4. The group of $\emptyset$-definable automorphisms of  $\overline{\{\emptyset\}}$.

Does some statement along these lines hold?

It at least works out [in ACF](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275394/can-a-nontrivial-phi-in-gal-bar-k-bar-k-preserve-all-algebraically-clos), where $\ker \chi$ consists only of Frobenius automorphisms as soon as the transcendence degree of $A$ is at least 2.

**EDIT** In view of the counterexamples in the comments that I should have noticed, there should be an additional "non degeneracy" hypothesis. Let's additionally stipulate that $\overline{A \cup B} \neq \bar A \cup \bar B$ unless $\bar A \subseteq  \bar B$ or $\bar B \subseteq \bar A$. That makes the kind of argument that works in the ACF case look plausible.

Comment: Why should the kernel of $\chi$ should have anything to do with the groups numbered 2, 3, and 4 in general? For example, let $T$ be the theory of a set of size $3$ with no extra structure, and let $A$ be a model. Then $L$ is trivial, and $\text{ker} \chi$ is $S_3$, while the other three groups are trivial.

Comment: I know you said $T$ should be "nice" and $A$ should be "large enough", so the example above may not apply. But my point is that condition 4 is explicitly a definability condition, and conditions 2 and 3 are related to definability (since they're about automorphism-invariance of automorphisms). But the condition that an automorphism fixes every algebraically closed set set-wise feels to me like it should be weaker than any sort of definability condition.

Comment: OK, better example: Let $T$ be the theory of an equivalence relation with infinitely many classes, each of size $3$. This is as nice as you like (uncountably categorical!). But $\text{ker}\, \chi$ is a product of lots of copies of $S_3$, while the other three groups are trivial.

Comment: Another example is Th(Z, S) (Z = integers, S = successor relation). 1, 2, 4 are trivial, 3 is (Z, +) (the iterates of S).

Comment: Another example is: let T have an equivalence relation w/ infinitely many classes each of size 3, but also add infinitely many constant symbols, all in distinct classes. Let G be the two-element group. Then the group in 1 is $G^{\mathbb{N}} \times S_3^\kappa$, the groups in 2 and 3 are both $G^{\mathbb{N}}$, and the group in 4 is the subgroup of $G^{\mathbb{N}}$ consisting of the functions of finite support and cofinite support.

Comment: Or actually, the group in 1 is just $S_3^\kappa$

Comment: Good points, if you'll bear with me I have one more condition which might salvage things.

Comment: The non-degeneracy hypothesis holds whenever we eliminate imaginaries, but elimination of imaginaries changes none of the groups.

Comment: @DouglasUlrich I don't think elimination of imaginaries implies nondegeneracy in the sense I mean. For example, the theory of an infinite set with two constants $a,b$ eliminates imaginaries, but it is degenerate: $\bar A$ consists of finite tuples in $A \cup \{a,b\}$. I'm using $\bar A$ to denote the algebraic closure of $A$. It does seem wrong, though, that degeneracy is not biinterpretation-invariant whereas everything else is. Let's say a theory is degenerate if it is biinterpretable with a degenerate theory. It's not a very elegant condition, sure, and perhaps something stronger is needed.

Comment: @AlexKruckman The reason I think something like this should hold in some generality is that the argument I linked to showing this holds in ACF seems to basically just rely on there being "enough" different generating sets for a given algebraically closed set. I'm supposing the language must exist in stability theory to formulate a general condition making that precise so one could replicate this ACF argument abstractly. I suppose I initially thought that a size condition on $A$ might guarantee "enough" bases, but now it seems more is necessary.

Comment: @Tim Campion: Ah, I meant if $T$ *was* the canonical elimination of imaginaries.

Comment: @DouglasUlrich -- you're right, I'm being stupid. This nondegeneracy condition is just wrong.